# Devise login form in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to have the Devise log in form be on my home page.

When I just copy the form over, of course I get errors because the 'resource' variables and etc are not set in the action.

I found this solution on the internet: http://pupeno.com/blog/show-a-devise-log-in-form-in-another-page/

However, his solution is to set the needed variables in a module called ContentHelper.

Where do I put this code? I tried putting it in the initializers, but I still get the error about 'resource' variable not existing

Comment: Thank you life saver. I also wanna perform login functionality in a different controller, not devise, and I searched for a few hours until I see you quenstion :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the module in a file in `app/helpers/content_helper.rb`. If you still get errors add `helper :content` to your controller.

Answer (score 20):

See if this entry in the devise wiki helps you!

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app